# Android: Looking for different TimePicker Style

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, timepicker

Hello everyone a brief question - I have been hunting for this style of TimePicker to no avail so far(as shown on [DroidDraw](http://www.droiddraw.org/widgetguide.html)):

[image: TimePicker]

I start doubting the existence of that style ... :P Anyone who's got a clue on how to get my hands on it - thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Ready4Android

Comment: have you tried downloading the DroidDraw library and adding it to your project so you can use the custom `TimePicker` included with it?

Comment: @willytate: Mhhh have u tried this urself btw xD ? I just downloaded the jar.file (of the standalone version) and added it to my project - just class files, no javadoc (or source) is available for the package org.droiddraw.widget, where I found a TimePicker. I can't look into their TimePicker class and I can't add it either, because it has an empty constructor and is not accepted by the addView method of my layout... Any suggestions?

Comment: No, I haven't tried it ><  I just figured the widgets they show would be what their library provides?  I apologize if this isn't the case :[

Comment: @willytate: I am afraid its not the case :( but thanks for the tip anyway :) i'll go on with my custom implementation then :)

Comment: Look at the answer by sunshine in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427458/how-do-you-use-custom-datepicker-and-timepicker-skins