# Change TimePicker style

Tags: android, timepicker

I want to customize time picker style to default style in Android 4. I want to use this style either I am using Android 2.2 or any version.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427458/how-do-you-use-custom-datepicker-and-timepicker-skins http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969513/how-can-i-override-timepicker-to-change-text-color

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at Holo Everywhere library which aims to port Holo theme for android 1.6 onwards here: https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere

Comment: upgrade your link... this nomore exists.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to get the [TimePicker's source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/TimePicker.java) with all classes & resources that are required, put in in your project and then use them instead of the one's provided by the platform itself.

Comment: is there any other way of doing this.?? Can't we simply use some drawable